# http 401 for Spring Tutorial when running "ant list"

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I'm tired of Googling.

I'm getting this stacktrace when running "ant list" from the command-line:

```
/home/tgh/workspace/FiLTH/build.xml:138: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask.execute(ListTask.java:51)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Here is my build.xml:

```
<property name="src.dir" value="src/main/java"/>
<property name="web.dir" value="src/main/resources"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="target"/>
<property name="name" value="filth"/>

<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="jar">
        <include name="*/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <!-- We need the servlet API classes: -->
    <!--  * for Tomcat 5/6 use servlet-api.jar -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
        <include name="servlet*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
</path>

<target name="usage">
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="${name} build file"/>
    <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
    <echo message=""/>
    <echo message="build     --> Build the application"/>
    <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application as directory"/>
    <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file"/>
    <echo message="install   --> Install application in Tomcat"/>
    <echo message="reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat"/>
    <echo message="start     --> Start Tomcat application"/>
    <echo message="stop      --> Stop Tomcat application"/>
    <echo message="list      --> List Tomcat applications"/>
    <echo message=""/>
</target>

<target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
           deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
    <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
    <war destfile="${name}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </war>
    <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="*.war"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Tomcat tasks - remove these if you don't have Tomcat installed -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->

<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
    <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
      <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
         <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
         <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
         <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
         <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
      </fileset>

</path>

<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
    <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"
             war="${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
    <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
    <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
    <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
             path="/${name}"/>
</target>

<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
             username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
             password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>
```

Here is my build.properties:

```
appserver.home=/home/tgh/workspace/tomcat
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib
deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/html
tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
tomcat.manager.password=s3cret
```

Here is the contents of tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>

<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
```

Anyone know what's going on?  Thanks!

Comment: HTTP 401 means that there was an authentication failure. At first glance, I'm guessing that the problem is that you have two 'tomcat' users defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by  GreyBeardedGeek 401 clearly means authorization issue. 
You will need to configure manager role and access to tomcat, from your tomcat-users.xml i can see two issue 
1) tomcat user has been defined twice 
2) no role defined as "manager"

i think it you tomcat-users.xml should look like

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>

<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui,manager"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
```

i am not sure what/how you are going to use manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx but for security purpose you should also remove un-necessary users "both" and "role1".

for configuring manager access you can refer to tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html)

Comment: It is now working with a simple tomcat-users.xml file like so:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager"/>
</tomcat-users>`
(sorry for the bad formatting)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure in tomcat-users.xml as below

```
<user name="<username>" password="<password>" roles="manager-script,manager-gui,manager,manager-jmx"/>
```